# How to test the new Mastercard cards?

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, mastercard, bluesnap

I read this update from Mastercard about their new BIN series that starts with 2:
https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/issuers/get-support/2-series-bin-expansion.html

I want to make sure we’re not getting any issues with our BlueSnap account – can anyone tell me how to test this? I can’t find any test card information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that’s true – recently MC decided to update their BIN numbers and in addition to the BIN ranges that starts with 5 (510000 to 559999), there are new ranges that starts with 2 - 222100 to 272099.
If you are working with BlueSnap – you shouldn’t worry about this change, the relevant updates are already covered in BlueSnap and you can test them in your sandbox using this test card: 2223000048400011.
However, if for some reason you’re managing your own validation tools while integrating with BlueSnap -  you must make sure that your setup is supporting the new MC ranges to prevent transaction failure and penalties.
There is a great explanation about this in this link: https://chargebacks911.com/mastercard-new/

I hope this information was useful..